# Highlighting words in forms if they are too long

Tags: forms, textpos

I am using the following code to have LaTeX fill paper forms for bank payments. The single cells in the form have a maximum width so my question is the following: Can I make LaTeX highlight those text sequences that exceed a predefined width e.g. in red?

If for example the "Account holder" text get too long I'd like to have it appear in red font color in the PDF.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

\begin{document}\ocrfamily 

\begin{textblock}{3.5}[0,0](0.8,3.5)1234567890\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{6}[0,0](4.8,3.4)Account holder\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{2.5}[0,0](11.75,3.5)40,00\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{12}[0,0](0.75,5)Some Description\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image: bargeld]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking Fran's code just a teeny bit further, one can test the length of the item and compare it to the allocated size, and only do the `\fbox` if it is exceeded.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

\newcommand\BankForm[4]{%
\begin{textblock}{#1}[0,0](#2,#3)%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#4}% 
\setbox0=\hbox{#4}%
\ifdim\wd0>\hsize
  {\color{red}\fbox{\makebox[\hsize][l]{\phantom{#4}}}}% Uncomment to show edges 
\fi
\end{textblock}
}

\begin{document}\ocrfamily 

\BankForm{3.5}{0.8}{3.5}{1234567890}
\BankForm{4}{4.8}{3.5}{Too long account}
\BankForm{2.5}{11.75}{3.5}{40}
\BankForm{12}{0.75}{5}{Some Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the emphasis level needed to be increased, the text itself could also be made in the highlight color:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

\newcommand\BankForm[4]{%
\begin{textblock}{#1}[0,0](#2,#3)%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#4}% 
\setbox0=\hbox{#4}%
\ifdim\wd0>\hsize
  \textcolor{red}{\makebox[0pt][l]{#4}%
  \fbox{\makebox[\hsize][l]{\phantom{#4}}}}% Uncomment to show edges 
\else
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#4}% 
\fi
\end{textblock}
}

\begin{document}\ocrfamily 

\BankForm{3.5}{0.8}{3.5}{1234567890}
\BankForm{4}{4.8}{3.5}{Too long account}
\BankForm{2.5}{11.75}{3.5}{40}
\BankForm{12}{0.75}{5}{Some Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: MWE]

An approach to check that is show a box with the horizontal size of the text blocks. In this MWE, your only need to uncomment the line 16 to show the red boxes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

\newcommand\BankForm[4]{%
\begin{textblock}{#1}[0,0](#2,#3)%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#4}% 
%{\color{red}\fbox{\makebox[\hsize][l]{\phantom{#4}}}}% Uncomment to show edges 
\end{textblock}
}

\begin{document}\ocrfamily 

\BankForm{3.5}{0.8}{3.5}{1234567890}
\BankForm{4}{4.8}{3.5}{Too long account}
\BankForm{2.5}{11.75}{3.5}{40}
\BankForm{12}{0.75}{5}{Some Description}

\end{document}
```